# accessing referenced libraries from packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I can only access referenced library classes if I save my classes in the default package. If I try to access them from any other package I get "className cannot be resolved". Any idea why this could happen?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That package is from the standard library of Princeton's IntroCS Course after a quick Google.

If you follow down to the FAQ on the page
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

> Q. If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no
>   longer access the libraries in stdlib.jar. Why not? 
>   A. The libraries
>   in stdlib.jar are in the "default" package. In Java, you can't access
>   classes in the default package from a named package. If you need to
>   use our libraries with a named package, you can use the packaged
>   version stdlib-package.jar.

Download package jar file:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar

Right click project folder and add external JAR.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*;
```

Add above line to the classes where you need to reference the classes. 
The first line references the correct package name and the * wildcard imports all the classes within it.

:) Hope that helps.

//Edit - If you right click the project folder and use "Organize Imports" it will be faster so you don't have to manually add to each class.

Comment: this version has a package name, I followed Fabian's advice and created my own jar with package. Thanks! you saved me some time with building my own libraries.

Comment: looks like there's no packaged version for algs4.jar

Comment: NM found it: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4-package.jar

This whole scenario was this described in the FAQ:

Q. If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no longer access the libraries in stdlib.jar or algs4.jar. Why not?
A. The libraries in stdlib.jar and algs4.jar are in the "default" package. In Java, you can't access classes in the default package from a named package. If you need to use our libraries with a named package, you can use these package versions: stdlib-package.jar and algs4-package.jar.

Comment: For anyone using the version from algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4/-package.jar the import path is `import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*`

Comment: @ddayan I would suggest you change the best answer to Jasmine's answer. Also, can anyone explain why someone would develop a .jar that can only be accessed by the default package?

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. Provided the good link to the good jar avoiding us to create a custom jar. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you've proper `import` declarations and the type you are refering to has `public` access modifier.

Import declaration for Types in the default package are per definition impossible. JLS specifies that it is a compile time error to import a type from an unnamed package.
You must access your class via reflections or much better do not ever use the default package. Eclipse should show you a warning when you want to create a type inside default package, because it's generally discouraged.

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse then try hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind the type name in the class where you want to use it. Eclipse should give you all matching opportunities and will add the import automatically for you if you select your class.

Comment: Well the referenced class dont have any package name so I'm not sure what to specify in the import declaration, and eclipse doesn't give any fix suggestions.

Comment: It's because importing types from unnamed packages are not valid. So there is no way to import the class. You've to move your class to a named package or access it via reflection. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So do you mean I need to change the Jar file I'm importing? so the classes in the jar file belong to a package? I don't think I can change the jar so I should not create any packages in my project? I'm not sure thats right...

Comment: I added an image to explain the problem

Comment: Well, beside that's a questionable lib when its using the default package it is very clear: You cannot import from the default package. Period. Nevertheless you can access these classes from your classes in the default package, because you then don't need the import. You can build your own jar file and move the classes to a named package. Or at least you can access them via reflection.

Comment: I built a custom jar before I saw your comment and realised you were spot on! Not sure how I never encountered this behaviour before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the package into other package.

Classes in one package cannot directly reference to other package unless its get referenced.